# A func returning a func in Swift

Tags: swift

This gives me an error in the playground.

```
func returnAFunc() -> ()
{
    func f(){ println("hello") }

    return f
}
```

Now I read that as a func named "returnAFunc" which returns another func which doesn't return a value. Correct? But it doesn't work. I have to do this:

```
func returnAFunc() -> () -> ()     // or this (() -> ())
{
    func f(){ println("hello") }

    return f
}
```

Ok that doesn't seem right. Can someone explain?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The type signature of your first `returnAFunc` is `() -> ()`, which means a function that takes no arguments and returns nothing. The type for your second function is `() -> () -> ()`, which means a function that takes no arguments and returns a function with type `() -> ()` (i.e. a function that takes no arguments and returns nothing).

I think your basic misunderstanding is that `()` represents a function type. Instead, it's the same thing as Void. Once you understand this, the only other potential "gotcha" is to remember that the arrow is right-associative.

EDIT: Since I got the checkmark, I think it's worth calling attention to [IMSoP's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24250880/50742), which does a great job of explaining how to read the type in more detail.

Comment: Yes, I believe there is some confusion on my part, because of what you pointed out. I think they need to make this clearer in a future iteration of Swift.

Answer (score 6):

Lets break down your definition:

```
func returnAFunc() -> ()
```

- `func` keyword
- `returnAFunc` function name
- `()` parameters expected (void/none)
- `->` read as "returns"
- `()` void return type

So this function takes no parameters, and returns nothing.

The working version breaks down like this:

```
func returnAFunc() -> () -> ()
```

- `func` keyword
- `returnAFunc` function name
- `()` parameters expected (void/none)
- `->` read as "returns"
- `() -> ()` return type is another function specification:

  - `()` returned function takes no parameters
  - `->` read as "returns"
  - `()` returned function returns void

So this function takes no parameters, and returns (a function which takes no parameters and returns nothing). (Eesh, even in English I feel the need to add extra parentheses to that...)

Answer (score 3):

`()` is an empty tuple.  Swift uses it as the return type of a void function, so

```
  () -> ()
```

Is the signature of a function that takes no parameters and returns nothing (is void)

So,

```
func myFunc() -> ()
```

declares a function that returns nothing (is void), and

```
func myFunc() -> () -> ()
```

declares a function that returns a function, which takes no arguments and returns nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Your first example reads as "Function `returnAFunc` takes no arguments, and returns no values." Your second example correctly defines the return type as "Function `returnAFunc` takes no arguments, and returns a function that takes no arguments and returns no arguments."

The syntax is a bit wonky, to be sure, but once you get used to it, it's pretty straightforward to see what's going on.

In addition, the Swift type `void` is represented as "`()`", so you could also interpret this as "Function `returnAFunc` takes a void argument (which means no argument) and returns a void type (which means no argument)." I'm not sure that's actually what's happening behind the scenes, though.